# How to delete duplicates from ListView<HashMap<>>

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

The list repeats many of the same values, I would like to delete them. Maybe someone will check what is wrong or give a new way to do this?

```
class Duplicats implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        HashMap<String, String> test1 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj1;
        HashMap<String, String> test2 = (HashMap<String, String>) obj2;
        if(test1.get("name").equalsIgnoreCase(test2.get("name"))){
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you're ok with the values in `obj1` replacing those in `obj2` (or vice-versa if you switch the order):

```
Map<String, String> objCombined = new HashMap<String, String>();

//Add the 2nd object's items
objCombined.putAll( (HashMap<String, String>) obj2);

//Add the first object's items, replacing duplicates
objCombined.putAll( (HashMap<String, String>) obj1);
```

If you want obj2's values to be the ones retained, just switch the order of the `put` calls above.

Comment: So how i should modify my code? I want to list without duplicats

Comment: @Torwopik Your code does not actually list anything. it's a comparator which can be used to alter a list. Instead of using your code shown above at all, just use the code in my answer and then `objCombined` is your list without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

So how do it from this position?

```
{
 ...

                    HashMap<String, String> controllers = new HashMap<>();

                    controllers.put("id", id);
                    controllers.put("name", name);

                    DevicesList.add(controllers);


                    }
```